# Hosting custom premium WordPress plugin and give plugin updates from private server

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have developed a custom plugin in WordPress and i have hosted it onto my private server. Clients who are having the subscription with my can get auto updates. (Licensiing is also active).

I want to secure the updates only to the licensed members of my website. But currently my update link is public (similar to any other WordPress plugin). Available updates store to the `_site_transient_update_plugins` option and my plugin's download link is also available in it (package link). Anyone can access the zip from here.

What i want is to secure this link so only licensed members can get the downloads Please guive any security measures to follow.

I have thorowly studied a premium plugin who do the same, and i found that they host their package onto the AWS and protect the download URL with some AWS URL based file protection like "X-Amz-Content-Sha256", "X-Amz-SignedHeaders", "X-Amz-Signature". Such params are in their Package URL.

I want something like this from my own private server.

Thank you.

Comment: Those specific headers are only about validating the integrity of the payload being delivered, they don't really "protect" anything from a licensing standpoint.

Comment: One system that you could use to attempt to address this would be to limit things by domain/url, as stored in WordPress. When someone "activates" their license, call `get_site_url()` (or similar), pass that to your server. You can then store that domain and issue an opaque token bound to that domain. When an update request comes in, have the client send both the domain and token, and if they don't match, deny the request. If they do, redirect to a download that expires after a short amount of time.